# Where is the advanced class trainer for smugglers?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Where is the advanced class trainer for smugglers?  I can't find where I am supposed to choose my specialization.

Comment: This isn't totally clear to me but may help: http://www.torhead.com/mission/1dLbAdO

Comment: Are you level 10 yet? If you're not you can't pick an advanced class.

Answer (score 6):

As you advance in your class missions, you will eventually (somewhere between level 9-11 usually) receive a mission directing you to "The Fleet". As soon as you exit the first lift that opens to the main area, there will be a quest giver in front of you and a little to the left. They will give you mission to direct you to your advanced class trainer.

Remember, your advanced class can not be changed once chosen! Choose carefully! (The developers have commented that they *might* allow AC changes in the future, but they're not sure if they're going to or not yet.)

Answer (score 0):

There are also trainers in the Senate Commercial District on Coruscant.  For Empire players there are trainers in the upper East part of Kaas City on Dromund Kaas.

Answer (score 0):

When you are level 10 as Musafa said, you get to the main fleet wehre there is a questgiver that gives you a quest to talk to 2 of the advanced classes. Each one will give you some explanation about your class and what they are good for. Then after you've done that you need to go back to the questgiver and choose wich advanced class you want to be.

After you chosen please notice that there will be a bag in your inventory containing an advanced class weapon. For example if you took mercenary you'll get a second blue gun ect...

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the flight pad on Coruscant, there is a fat guy sitting on crates. Talk to him to start your quest.

Comment: Try adding more details - Screenshot, map, source (if got from another site) to increase your answer.